# react-native-copilot Automatic movement of tooltips in ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview, ref, github-copilot

While working with this library, if the hints are not in the screen area, the scrolling does not automatically move to the next hint, but stays in place.

I tried to use scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo in stepChange, but scrolling occurs after the next step and knocks down the position.